# Uninstall All Add-ins starting with U

Tags: vba, excel, add-in

I want a VBA code which uninstalls all the add-ins starting with the letter U.

Something like

```
Application.Addins("U%").Installed = False.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use loop and the other solution which you know from the other question of yours:

```
Sub Addin_start_with_U()

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim tmpAddIn As AddIn
    For Each tmpAddIn In Application.AddIns
        'optionally we write add-in name to immediate
        Debug.Print tmpAddIn.Name

        'add-in name could start with 'u' or 'U'- both will be unistalled:
        If UCase(Left(tmpAddIn.Name, 1)) = "U" Then
            tmpAddIn.Installed = False
        End If
    Next

    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```